# QGIS Server down (Version 3.10.2)

Tags: qgis-server

I've been having issues with displaying basemaps using the QuickMaps Services plugin and I've tried the connecting to Tiles servers through the XYZ Tiles channel to display basemaps. Using both methods I just get a blank work space with no basemap.

I have reason to believe that there is something wrong with the server connection as I get this error when I try to Check Version Number:
[image: Error pop-up]

Also, I can't seem to access the Plug-in library and the repository is indicated as "unavailable":[image]

Has anyone encountered what I believe is a server connection issue and has anyone been able to fix it?

SOLVED: It turns out I had Use Proxy for Web Access checked before which resulted in problems accessing the internet [image]

Comment: Works for me, is this still an issue for you?

Comment: still an issue, I'll try reaching out to IT at my organization to see if they know.

Comment: If you're behind a corporate proxy, try specifying the proxy in QGIS network settings https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#network-settings